# Shared Element Transition with rounded MaterialCardView

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a shared element transition between 2 activities.

The shared elements are an image, and a button.

These are the 2 layouts of the 2 activities:

1- Source

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:transitionName="card"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:transitionName="frame"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/test"
                android:transitionName="image" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:text="Button"
                android:transitionName="button"
                app:cornerRadius="100dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2- Target

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transitionName="card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/test"
            android:transitionName="image" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:transitionName="button"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cornerRadius="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As said, the elements are the image inside the card, and the button. The image moves up and the button moves down. The button background and text color are different in the second activity.

This is how I'm building the transition:

```
val intent = Intent(this, TestActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent, ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this,
                Pair<View, String>(card, "card"),
                Pair<View, String>(button, "button")
            ).toBundle())
```

The main problem is, I had to move the entire card because moving only the image made the rounded corners disappear and reappear in a very strange way.

But moving the entire card had created another strange animation. The image now gets a margin in the bottom on entering and exiting.

There is also the matter that the button only moves from one location to the other, no other attributes are changed.

What is the best way to create this transition? Is there something I have to do to fix it? Or is the only solution to create a custom transition?